# What is the best way to debug a post to the WebToLead servelet?

Tags: api

I have a VisualPage form that posts to

`https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8`

After the post my browser correctly gets redirected to the post value specified in `retURL`, but the lead is not added to the database.

What is the best way to debug this problem?

Also, if someone has a list of the required post fields that the servlet expects as mandatory. Are the key names case sensitive?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if the key names are case-sensitive (I expect they are), but the identifiers for custom fields change from org to org. If you have Lead.My_field__c in a sandbox, it will have a different id in production. The only fields that are mandatory are:

1. Lead.LastName
2. Lead.Status (update: this may be set automatically by SF)
3. Any custom field you mark as required in the definition
4. An HTML hidden input for oid, which is your org's id

In addition, there are form fields you can add that put your form into debug mode. The following was taken from UI's Web2Lead generation tool:

```
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  NOTE: These fields are optional debugging elements. Please uncomment    -->
<!--  these lines if you wish to test in debug mode.                          -->
<!--  <input type="hidden" name="debug" value=1>                              -->
<!--  <input type="hidden" name="debugEmail"                                  -->
<!--  value="myemail@mydomain.com">                                           -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
```

Enabling debug mode will do the following:

1. Not submit the Lead to your org
2. Display all form elements in your browser

In my experience, however, we receive an email whenever Salesforce cannot generate the Lead from the form's data. If you do not receive these emails you might be sending the form to the wrong org or have something mis-configured.

Comment: +1 for this good answer! I sure hope there is more that can be done, because all I got from debug mode was: `Reason: Your Lead could not be processed.`

Comment: I presume `oid` would also be a required field, right? If I'm posting to a custom object, anything that specifies the object?

Comment: Yes, but oid is not a Lead field - it is your org's id. I will update my answer.

Comment: I hand-coded the form using a similar form (that posts successfully) as a starting point. Is there a way to look up what `00N70000001ngMx`-like key to use for each object field? I am trying to guess which one is the Lead.Status

Comment: The easiest way I've found is to just use the UI and generate a Web2Lead form with *all* of your fields and keep that for reference. Standard fields, like Source, do not have custom IDs. And it turns out I think Status might be set by default to Open.

Comment: @JannieT the `00N...` thing is the custom field's Id (like all account Ids begin with `001` and if you type it in the browser you end up on Accounts Tab). So go to Setup, Lead fields and examine the links :)

Comment: Do you know what sort of validation is done on the data other than checking that all required fields are there?

Comment: Any validation rules you have set up on the object, but the email would state that in the Reason. Have you tried manually entering in the same data that Web2Lead rejected?

Comment: Yes, I can add the info manually, but this is now becoming a new question: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5132/why-is-my-webtolead-form-not-submitting. According to the official FAQ [How can our webmaster test the Web-to-Lead page?](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=faq_leads_how_can_our_webmaster.htm&language=en_US) you are right on this question. I was really hoping there was something more useful.